libgcov version mismatch on arm-none-eabi when using __gcov_dump()
Failing to get gcov to perform coverage analysis on microcontroller.
This the compiler version
arm-none-eabi-g++.exe (GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain 10.3-2021.10) 10.3.1 20210824 (release)
The is the error message piped back to the host computer from the ucontroller running
libgcov profiling error:<master>:Version mismatch - expected 10.3 (experimental) (B03r) got (unknown) (ð)
This is the code which invokes __gcov_dump(). It always gives the error above.
The mismatch is not true. the build file clearly specifies 10.3 bin with all the .exe's
void hal_entry(void)
{
int i = 10;
while (i--)
{  
  BlinkLed();

Wait(duration);
}
 \__gcov_dump();  

}
Tried setting the version code to match what it said it expected by using a #define GCOV_VERSION 10.3.
but that failed.
Tried attempting replace gcov_version(...) with a local version but this failed too.
